# Unable to build OpenNI 2.2 for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, openni

I am trying to interface ASUS Xtion PRO LIVE Depth sensor with my smartphone. For that, I need OpenNI shared libraries for Android. I am using cygwin on Windows and I followed [these steps:](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2)

1. Download NDK
2. defind NDK_ROOT path
3. run ReleaseVersion.py

But I am stuck on 3rd Step:

```
Creating installer for OpenNI 2.2 android
make: Entering directory '/home/OF/structure/OpenNI2_modified/Packaging/AndroidBuild'
Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script
StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
Compile++ thumb  : EventBasedRead <= main.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OpenNI.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OniStream.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OniSensor.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OniDeviceDriver.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OniDevice.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OniDataRecords.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : OpenNI2 <= OniRecorder.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OpenNI.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OniDataRecords.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OniDeviceDriver.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OniDevice.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OniStream.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Samples/EventBasedRead/main.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OniSensor.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniDataRecords.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniDataRecords.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OpenNI.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OpenNI.o] Error 1
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniDeviceDriver.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniDeviceDriver.o] Error 1
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniDevice.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniDevice.o] Error 1
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniSensor.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniSensor.o] Error 1
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/EventBasedRead/main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/EventBasedRead/main.o] Error 1
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniStream.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniStream.o] Error 1
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/OpenNI2/Source/Core/OniRecorder.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniRecorder.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OpenNI2/OniRecorder.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/OF/structure/OpenNI2_modified/Packaging/AndroidBuild'
Build failed!
```

EDIT: ----------------------------------------------------------------------

I was able to build OpenNI2 for Android in Mac OSX. I have uploaded `OpenNI-android-2.2.tar` shared library, and ini files present in `Final` folder after successful build, in case if anyone else might want them:
http://1drv.ms/1PbYhhW

Answer (score 0):

I build android nkd r8e with no error. And OpenNI2 source code is https://github.com/occipital/openni2 or https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2, I can build both source code.